# How to get the last 200 candles from bybit

Tags: algorithmic-trading, binance, tradingview-api, binance-api-client

```
import bybit
import pprint

api_key_i = "my key"
api_secret_i = "mysecret"

client = bybit.bybit(test=True, api_key="api_key_i", api_secret="api_secret_i")
x = client.LinearKline.LinearKline_get(symbol="DOTUSDT", interval="5", **{'from':1581231260}).result()
print(len(x[0]['result']))
pprint.pprint(x[0]['result'])
```

I know I have to change this value **{'from':1581231260} but no idea how to change this. I have never seen this kind of syntax before.

https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/linear/?python#t-orderbook

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is get the current UTC datetime, use a floor method that rounds that datetime to 5 min (e.g. 12:07:53 will become 12:05:00) and subtract (200 * 5 min) from it, that datetime (is the oldest candle) needs to be converted to an unix timestamp and set in the from parameter :). Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I needed to perform the same query and I did it with the method written in the official source [here](https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/v5/websocket/public/orderbook).